# 503 error from Google cloud repository - unable to clone

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-source-repos, google-cloud-repository

I have not been able to access (clone) google cloud repos since this evening. Getting a 503 service unavailable error. The UI (cloud console) seems to work though.

Anyone facing similar issues ? Was there an outage ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like google cloud storage (https://storage.googleapis.com/...) is down and not accessible from India (I've checked this access from Bangalore and Delhi).
Apparently, the same URL is working from other locations (Skype for instance displays the image which means skype server running in which ever location is able to access the same URL at this time).

There are outages of different google services reported today from India (see http://downdetector.com/status/google)